# Слайдер в слайдере slickGoTo() не работает

Tags: jquery, slider

Есть такой пример слайдера в слайдере:

```js
$('.sl').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  draggable: false,
  beforeChange: function(){
    $('.sl-i').slick('slickGoTo', 0,  true);
  }
});

$('.sl-i').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false
});
```

```css
.box {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.sl-item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.box-sm {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="sl">
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Не пойму почему не работает `beforeChange` и `'slickGoTo'`. При листании основного слайдера внутренние должны перестраиваться на первый слайд. Что не так делаю?

Comment: может надо использовать `$('.sl-i').slickGoTo(0);`?

Comment: @Sublihim, без разницы.

Comment: тогда вопрос, правильно ли вы используете beforeChange? если добавить туда простой алерт, он сработает?

Comment: на сайте разработчиков обработка beforeChange представлена следующим кодом `$('.your-element').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  console.log(nextSlide);
});`

Comment: @Sublihim, так тоже не хочет работать, зависает вообще

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слайдер-родитель ловит событие `beforeChange` при каждом перемещении в слайдерах-потомках. Если в ответ на это событие перемещать детей, всё зависает. Это можно увидеть, отправляя записи в консоль.

Чтобы событие в потомке не доплывало до родителя, добавил `return false;`. Метод `stopPropagation()` не подействовал.

Проверьте результат: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/gLJGZE

```js
$('.sl').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  draggable: false
});

$('.sl-i').slick({
  slidesToShow: 2,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false
});

$('.sl').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
//console.log('beforeChange');
  $('.sl-i').slick('slickGoTo', 0,  true);
});

$('.sl-i').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
//console.log('beforeChange child');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.box {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.sl-item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.box-sm {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 2px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  
<div class="sl">
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sl-item">
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="sl-i">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="box-sm">3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Супер, огромное спасибо!!!!!